# Set difference for jsonb

Tags: postgresql, json

The *hstore* type in Postgres provides an [operation to calculate the set difference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) (EXCEPT) of two records. Is there something similar for jsonb? The best I've got is `SELECT * FROM jsonb_each('{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb) EXCEPT SELECT * FROM jsonb_each('{"a":1}'::jsonb)`, but I don't know how to convert it back to jsonb.

I want to use this to calculate the difference (the changed values) between `OLD` and `NEW` in a trigger.

Comment: https://github.com/glynastill/pg_jsonb_delete_op  if you are looking for an audit trigger, see here: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: This blog post describes exactly my problem. There's no `jsonb - jsonb`. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It links to an implementation of a delete operator: https://github.com/glynastill/pg_jsonb_delete_op

Answer (score 0):

As a_horse_with_no_name pointed in the comments to a blog post describing the problem that there is no operation for `jsonb - jsonb`, I found this solution:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  OLD CONSTANT RECORD := row(12, 'Test', false, 4);
  NEW CONSTANT RECORD := row(12, 'Test', true, NULL);
  data_diff jsonb;
BEGIN
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value) INTO STRICT data_diff
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(NEW))
        EXCEPT SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(OLD))
    ) as t;

    raise notice '%', data_diff;
END
$$;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).